# Overflow-y: scroll with overflow-x: visible

Tags: html, css, overflow

Is it possible to have an item overflow horizontally out of a vertically scroll-able list?

I have a codepen example here:

http://codepen.io/baskuipers/pen/GqQYRJ

```js
var $item = $('#1'),
  $button = $('.button');

$button.on("click", function() {
  $item.toggleClass('addMargin');
});
```

```css
.sidenav {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 20px;
}
.addMargin {
  margin-left: 60px;
}
.item {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
}
.sub-item {
  transition: margin-left 1s cubic-bezier(0.36, -0.48, 0, 2.22);
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidenav">
  <button class="button">test</button>
  <div class="item">
    <div id="1" class="sub-item"></div>
    <div class="sub-item"></div>
    <div class="sub-item"></div>
    <div class="sub-item"></div>
    <div class="sub-item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the example I'd like to have the yellow item stick out of the list.
It is not a problem about the visibility of the scrollbars.

Any suggestions? CSS / JavaScript?

Thanks!

Comment: @SeanLeBlanc, the OP's question is asking if an element can overflow along the x-axis while the y-axis is set to overflow scroll. The duplicate you posted is a different issue entirely...

Comment: @HunterTurner Answers in the question I referenced explain why the obvious solution to the OP's question (i.e. `overflow-x:visible; overflow-y:auto;`) wouldn't work and offer some workarounds. Would it be better to just comment with a link to the question in a case like this?

Answer (score 7):

After reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/6433475/4386196 it seems like the answer is no, it's not possible. You would need to set `overflow-x: visible`, but since you've set overflow-y then it is treated as `auto` which hides the content.

This probably doesn't solve your problem exactly, but if you add:

`margin-right: -100px; padding-right: 100px;`

to `.item` you can move the scrollbar and give more room for overflow within the box. Closest I could come to a solution.

Comment: Thanks! My case is slightly different from OP's - I needed to set 'overflow-y: visible' for children of div with 'overflow-x: hidden'. Following your idea, I ended up with adding 'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' for children, and it worked!

Comment: You should get a life-saver badge!